# mongodb $geointersects not working

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use `$geointersects` in `mongodb` to find the polygon in which the point is located.

For that in `php` i created the test data:

```
$collection = $db->selectCollection('countries');
$result = $collection->insertMany([
    [
        'c' => 'rus',
        'n' => 'Russia',
        'loc' => [
            "type" => "Polygon",
            "coordinates" => [
                [-109.95117, 39.77477],
                [-100.23926, 46.70974],
                [-94.41608,  37.78902],
                [-104.67541, 32.70375],
                [-109.95117, 39.77477]
            ]
       ]
    ],[
        'c' => 'can',
        'n' => 'Canada',
        'loc' => [
            "type" => "Polygon",
            "coordinates" => [
                [-100.15137, 46.83013],
                [-84.31555,  47.89965],
                [-82.39746,  37.78808],
                [-94.28467,  37.8228 ],
                [-100.15137, 46.83013]
            ]
       ]
    ]
]);
```

Result is:

[image]

Then in `Robomongo` I am making a select:

> db.getCollection('countries').find({"loc": { $geoIntersects:
>   {$geometry: {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -88.0123388, 41.8333926
>   ]}}}})

[image]

And no rows are returned! What might be an issue here?

Same in shell:

[image]

Here are the polygons I am testing against:

[image]

Here is the point (41.8333926, -88.0123388) [location](https://www.google.lv/maps/place/41%C2%B050'00.2%22N+88%C2%B000'44.4%22W/@39.5270188,-101.7789672,4.58z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.8333926!4d-88.0123388?hl=en):

[image]

Using the latest version of mongodb: 3.2.9.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is that structure of coordinates is incorrect. I wanted to create an index but it failed.. That is how this has been found out.

Correct array:

```
"coordinates" => [[
                [-109.95117, 39.77477],
                [-100.23926, 46.70974],
                [-94.41608,  37.78902],
                [-104.67541, 32.70375],
                [-109.95117, 39.77477]
            ]]
```

Therefore in my original question I put points into what supposed to be polys.